# Solve multi-dimensional optimization problem using basinhopping

Tags: optimization, python, scipy

I am searching for an optimization solution, which is a 8d vector representing 4 complex elements, where each element is within the complex circle with maximal radius 1.2.

The objective function is:

$$f: \left\|\mathbf{c}_{ref}-\mathbf{c}\right\|_{2}+\left|2-\|\mathbf{c}\|_{2}\right|$$

I am using the `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` module.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

class MyBounds(object):
    def __init__(self, xmax=[360, 360, 360, 360, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2], xmin=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ):
        self.xmax = np.array(xmax)
        self.xmin = np.array(xmin)

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        x    = kwargs["x_new"]
        tmax = bool(np.all(x <= self.xmax))
        tmin = bool(np.all(x >= self.xmin))
        return tmax and tmin

class MyTakeStep(object):
    def __init__(self, stepsize=45):
        self.stepsize = stepsize
    def __call__(self, x):
        s = self.stepsize
        x[0] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[1] += np.random.uniform(0, 2*s)
        x[2] += np.random.uniform(0, 3*s)
        x[3] += np.random.uniform(0, 4*s)
        s = 1
        x[4] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[5] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[6] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        x[7] += np.random.uniform(0, 1*s)
        return x

def f(input_list):
    polar_form = [rphi for rphi in zip(input_list[4:], input_list[:4])]
    x          = np.array([z(e[0], e[1]) for e in polar_form])
    # objective function componenets
    result  = abs(2 - np.linalg.norm(x, 2)) + np.linalg.norm(cref-x, 2)
    return result

def hopping_solver(min_f, min_x):
    minimizer_kwargs = {"method":'Nelder-Mead'}
    comb             = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    # define bounds
    mybounds   = MyBounds()
    mytakestep = MyTakeStep()
    optimal_c  = optimize.basinhopping(f, x0 = comb, niter=50000, T=45, stepsize=1, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, take_step=None, accept_test=mybounds, callback=None, interval=5000, disp=False, niter_success=None)

    min_x, min_f = optimal_c['x'], optimal_c['fun']
    print(optimal_c)
    return min_x, min_f

min_f = 10**10
min_x = []
min_x, min_f = hopping_solver(min_f, min_x)
```

My questions relate to the step essentially: My first elements are angles in [0, 360] and the others are in [0, 1.2]. What is a suitable way to define a good step here to balance between precision and fast processing?

I am aware that this code does not return the global minimum.

Also here I chose the center of my solutions space as $x_0$, are there recommendations on how to choose the starting point?

Comment: I would suggest you change from degrees to radians since it would give a better scaling of your problem, although I am not that sure it matters for Nelder-Mead. You could also use a higher order method when you are far away from the kinks in your objective function.

Comment: Actually, I think that the polar representation of complex numbers is singularly unsuitable to the problem here. It makes the problem non-unique (because you can add $2\pi$ to the angles and get another solution), and the spacing of points separated by a certain $(dr,d\phi)$ is non-uniform depending on where you are in the complex plane.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thank you for the suggestion, I am currently experimenting with angles in radians, which helped a bit with the scalibility. However, I still cannot get the correct solution despite trying different steps and the scipy iterations terminate successfully but do not get close enough to my solution. For example final f(x) = 1.34 where as it should get close to 0.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth well I agree but if you take a look at my bounds you will notice that I am limiting my solution's space to complex numbers with amplitude =< 1.2 and phases within [0, 360]. So I am only interested in solutions in that space and those should be unique.

Comment: Would you mind your optimization problem? Adding the restrictions, for example.

Comment: But step length determination becomes more complicated in polar coordinates. And you have to deal with bounds. When you have a bounds limited problem, you may also end up with multiple local minima where before you had only one global minimum.

Comment: @nicoguaro This is how my full minimization looks: $\left| \|\textbf{V}\|_{2}^2 - \|\textbf{A}.c\|_{2}^2 \right| + \|\textbf{c}_{ref}-\textbf{c}\|_{2} +  \left|2-\|\textbf{c}\|_{2}\right|$ where $\textbf{V}$ is a measurements vector and $\textbf{A}$ is a transformation matrix.

Comment: I am not sure, what restrictions are you referring to but at the moment I couldn't come up with any. @Wolfgang Bangerth well my understanding is that bounds limit the solutions space and help with efficiency so I am not sure I get your point? As for the polar coordinates, they seemed to be a trivial way of looping complex numbers space. What is your alternative suggestion?

Comment: Just work with real and imaginary part. For an example where these kinds of artificial variables + bounds create trouble, think of the function $f(r,\phi)=(r-1)^2+(\sin(\phi/2))^2$. This function clearly just has a single minimum at $z=r$ (which corresponds to $r=1,\phi=0$). But now think of what happens if you artificially introduce the bounds $-\pi/2 \le \phi\le 3\pi/2$. Now you have still the global minimum, but you've introduced another local minimum at $\phi=3\pi/2$ where the gradient is nonzero but you can't keep going downhill any more because of the bound.

Comment: I see your point. I tried an unbounded optimization but there wasn't a notable change in the results. Thank you all for the helpful comments. I improved my code accordingly but I am still struggling with the step update. I posted a new question [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/31362/scipy-basinhopping-custom-step-update-and-constrained-looping) . 
I look forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Geometrically, you are trying to find a point that is (i) as close as possible to the point $\mathbf c_{ref}$ and (ii) as close as possible to the sphere of radius 2. Your objective function is the sum of these two distances. The solution is that point $\mathbf c$ that is half-way between $\mathbf c_{ref}$ and the (closest point on the) sphere of radius 2, i.e., the solution if the vector
$$
  \mathbf c  = \frac 12 \left( \mathbf c_{ref} + 2 \frac{\mathbf c_{ref}}{\|\mathbf c_{ref}\|}\right).
$$
Written differently, you get that
$$
  \mathbf c  = \left( \frac 12  + \frac{1}{\|\mathbf c_{ref}\|}\right)
  \mathbf c_{ref}.
$$

Comment: Actually, *any* point on the connecting line between $\mathbf c_{ref}$ and the closest point on the sphere of radius 2 is a solution.

Comment: Well thank you for you suggestion, but it doesn't answer my question. Actually, my function is more complex than what I included, therefore my main concern here is proper initialization of the parameters. According to your solution my c is just $c_{ref}$ since I already have $\|c_{ref}\|_{2} = 2$.

Comment: Well, then yes, that's even simpler.